# Passing function while running a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am starting off with html5 and not sure if I'm doing anything wrong in here.

What I'm trying to achieve is create a portfolio of items and when one is selected, pass the selected item to a function to process it.

I have put up a simple jsfiddle in here https://jsfiddle.net/rohannayak90/9u9rtf84/

```
data = JSON.parse('{"error":false,"items":[{"id":1,"name":"John"},{"id":2,"name":"Jordan"}]}');

jQuery.each(data.items, function(counter, item) {
  //console.log(item);
  h = '<a href="#" onclick="' + generateCallBack(item) + ';">' + item.name + '</a></br>';
  $('#portfolio').append(h);
});

function generateCallBack(argItem) {
    return function() {
      itemSelected(argItem);
    };
};

function itemSelected(argItem) {
  //console.log(argItem.name);
  alert(argItem.name);
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the html5 tag for?

Comment: I don't understand the problem with the tag.

Comment: I do not see any HTML5 neither in the fiddle nor in the question itself. It's related to javascript, not HTML5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to to create HTML using [`jQuery()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes) and use [`.data(key, value)`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to store arbitrary value with element.

Additionally learn [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach, when generating elements dynamically.

*General Syntax*

```
$(staticParentContainer).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

Snippet for your solution

```js
$(function() {
  var data = JSON.parse('{"error":false,"items":[{"id":1,"name":"John"},{"id":2,"name":"Jordan"}]}');

  jQuery.each(data.items, function(counter, item) {
    //console.log(item);
    $('<a />', {
        href: '#',
        text: item.name,
        'class': 'myClass'
      })
      .data('item', item)
      .add('<br />')
      .appendTo('#portfolio');
  });

  $('#portfolio').on('click', 'a.myClass', function() {
    console.log($(this).data('item'));
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="showcase" class="container">
  <ul id="portfolio" class="grid">

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I went through the Event Delegation as suggested by you and seem to understand some of it. However I don't understand the way you add the </a> tag. I thought the .data('item', item) would add a data-item attribute to the <a> tag, but I don't find it in the compiled html. 

So how does the thing exactly work?

 Also how to add multiple tags like that for each loop entry? For example, an image along with the a tag.

Comment: @TheEvolvingMe, `.data()` use cache to store arbitrary data with element.  In the above example I have used `.add()` to add `br` similarly you can add image tag like `$('<a />', {
        href: '#',
        text: item.name,
        'class': 'myClass'
      })
      .data('item', item)
      .add('<br />').add($('<img />', {src: 'pathToImage'}))`

Comment: Thanks very much. Got it to work with the html layout that I needed to have.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to do something like this (you can change arrow functions to normal ones if that's a problem):

```
const data = JSON.parse('{"error":false,"items":[{"id":1,"name":"John"},{"id":2,"name":"Jordan"}]}');
const array = data.items;
const length = array.length;

let string = '';
data.items.map(item => {
    string += '<a href="#">' + item.name + '</a></br>';
});

const portfolio = document.getElementById('portfolio');
portfolio.innerHTML += string;

portfolio.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if(event.target.tagName !== 'A') return;

    let i = -1;
    while(++i < length) {
        if(array[i].name === event.target.textContent) {
            return alert(JSON.stringify(array[i].name)); // return ends the function and thus the loop too.
        }
    }
});
```

Plain Javascript. No jQuery crap.

Comment: This solution seems pretty straight forward. However, on the event listener, we are looping through all the items again to find the specified item. If we have 100's of items, would it have a performance hit?

Comment: With 100 items no, but you're right. That is very easily resolved by doing the loop via vanilla **while** loop for example and doing **break** after finding the desired element. I'll update my answer in a second to show that.

Comment: I like this, Good answer :)